# Creating a network in Python

Tags: python, networkx, adjacency-matrix

I am creating a network by specifying points and edges. However, I want to make this code more generic so that it can handle large number of `my_nodes` (say 100) and generate a connection matrix. This means that I don't want to enter the points and edges manually cause it will be cumbersome. For every node, there should be 4 edges and the numbering is shown below.

How do I do this? I present the output as well.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# build the network with relevant edges
G = nx.Graph()
points = {
    0: (1, 1), 1: (2, 1),
    'a':(1, 2), 'b':(2, 2),
    'c':(0, 1), 'd':(3, 1),
    'e':(1, 0), 'f':(2, 0)
}
for key, pos in points.items():
    G.add_node(key, pos=pos)
G.add_edge('a', 0, name=0)
G.add_edge('b', 1, name=1)
G.add_edge('c', 0, name=2)
G.add_edge(0, 1, name=3)
G.add_edge(1, 'd', name=4)
G.add_edge(0, 'e', name=5)
G.add_edge(1, 'f', name=6)

# find connected edges to nodes 0 and 1
my_nodes = [0, 1]  # could be more here
edges = {
    node: [G.get_edge_data(*edge)['name'] for edge in G.edges(node)]
    for node in my_nodes
}
# build matirx
mat = np.zeros((len(my_nodes), 7), dtype=np.uint8)
for i, node in enumerate(my_nodes):
    mat[i, edges[node]] = 1
    mat[i, edges[node]] = 1
A = pd.DataFrame(mat)
print(A)
```

Numbering is

[image]

The output is

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0
1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1
```

Comment: How do you specify the points and edges? Should they be randomly created?

Comment: Adjacency matrix is square by definition. Your output is not an adjacency matrix!

Comment: Yes they should be random. For every node, there should be 4 edges and the numbering is according to the previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75306778/generating-a-specific-adjacency-matrix-in-python/75308013?noredirect=1#comment132884937_75308013

Comment: Please edit the question to provide this information

Comment: You may better remove the adjacency matrix part from your question and just focus on the creation of you network. Could you further specify the point locations? Do they need to sit on a lattice?

Comment: The point locations could be random as long as they are connected as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nx.adjacency_matrix`:

```
# Keep only nodes with degree 4
my_nodes = [node for node, deg in G.degree if deg == 4]

A = pd.DataFrame(nx.adjacency_matrix(G).toarray(), index=G.nodes, columns=G.nodes)
B = A.loc[my_nodes]
```

Output:

```
>>> A
   0  1  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0
1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1
a  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
b  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
c  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
d  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
e  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
f  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0

>>> B
   0  1  a  b  c  d  e  f
0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0
1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: The output ```B``` doesn't match the output I have shown.

Comment: You don't want the node names? `df.columns = range(len(df.columns))`

Comment: I want the node numbers and apart from this, the other values are not the same as mine. Please see above.

Comment: Do you guarantee all edges have a name attribute?

Comment: Yes the edges should have.